# Change property name to the derived class name it has been instantiated with on serialization with Json.net

Tags: c#, .net, json, serialization, json.net

I am trying to serialize (and deserialize) my objects in .NET (standard) using the latest version of NewtonSoft.JSON.

Here are my classes :

```
public class BaseRequest
{
    public string UserName{ get; set; }
}
```

A request that derives from `BaseRequest` (I have many other such classes that derive from the `BaseRequest`):

```
public class GetDeviceRequest : BaseRequest
{
    public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
}
```

The request that I serialize to Json is created with the class :

```
public class CommunicationRequest
{
    public CommunicationRequest() { }

    public CommunicationRequest(BaseRequest baseRequest, string version ="1.1")
    {
        this.Version = version;
        this.Request = baseRequest;
    }

    public string Version { get; set; } = "1.1";
    public BaseRequest Request { get; set; }
}
```

Code I am using for serialization. I have not yet tested deserialization, but it should work the same way

```
GetDeviceRequest getDeviceRequest = new GetDeviceRequest()
{
    SerialNumber = "123456789",
    UserName = "john.doe"
};

CommunicationRequest request = new CommunicationRequest(getDeviceRequest);

var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings
{
    ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
};

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request, settings);
```

What I get as JSON:

```
{
   "version":"1.1",
   "request":{      
         "serialNumber":"123456789",
         "username":"john.doe"
   }
}
```

What I want:

```
{
   "version":"1.1",
   "getDeviceRequest":{      
         "serialNumber":"123456789",
         "username":"john.doe"
   }
}
```

I need to change `JsonProperty` name of `Request` to `GetDeviceRequest` dynamically based on what the name of the derived class is.

What I could have done :

```
[JsonProperty("DerievedClassName")]
public BaseRequest Request { get; set; }
```

This does not obviously work for me because the object is not instantiated and I cannot get the type to use something like `Request.GetType()`.

It would seem that the way is to implement my `ICustomContractResolver`, but I am not able to get a working `CustomContractResolver` for my use case.

Is there a way I can serialize the way I want to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need a custom `JsonConverter` for your `CommunicationRequest` class to handle the dynamic property name and also to be able to resolve it back to the correct type on deserialization (assuming you want to go round-trip with this).  Something like the following should suit your needs, but may need some tweaking.

```
public class CommunicationRequestConverter : JsonConverter
{
    NamingStrategy NamingStrategy { get; set; }

    public CommunicationRequestConverter(NamingStrategy namingStrategy)
    {
        NamingStrategy = namingStrategy;
    }

    public override bool CanConvert(Type objectType)
    {
        return objectType == typeof(CommunicationRequest);
    }

    public override void WriteJson(JsonWriter writer, object value, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        CommunicationRequest req = (CommunicationRequest)value;
        JObject jo = new JObject(
            new JProperty(GetPropertyName("Version"), req.Version),
            new JProperty(GetPropertyName(req.Request.GetType().Name), 
                          JObject.FromObject(req.Request, serializer))
        );
        jo.WriteTo(writer);
    }

    public override object ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, object existingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
    {
        JObject jo = JObject.Load(reader);

        string versionPropertyName = GetPropertyName("Version");
        JProperty requestProperty = jo.Properties().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name != versionPropertyName);

        Type baseRequestType = Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(BaseRequest)).GetTypes()
            .Where(t => t.IsClass && GetPropertyName(t.Name) == requestProperty.Name)
            .First();

        CommunicationRequest req = new CommunicationRequest
        {
            Version = (string)jo[versionPropertyName],
            Request = (BaseRequest)requestProperty.Value.ToObject(baseRequestType, serializer)
        };

        return req;
    }

    private string GetPropertyName(string name)
    {
        return NamingStrategy.GetPropertyName(name, false);
    }
}
```

Set up your serializer settings like this:

```
var ns = new CamelCaseNamingStrategy();
var settings = new JsonSerializerSettings { 
    ContractResolver = new DefaultContractResolver { NamingStrategy = ns },
    Converters = new List<JsonConverter> { new CommunicationRequestConverter(ns) },
    Formatting = Formatting.Indented
};
```

Here is a round-trip demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/kufBae

Comment: Cleaner than the solution I wrote taking help from your comment. Your code works fine and is simpler to read. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help.